# How to solve difference in number of records from a union query

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, union

I have a list of technicians and their number of patients, when I click on a technician I get the list of patients and their details. 
To do this, I have query that Returns the number of patients per technician and another returns the records of the patients.

```
SELECT *, SUM(Rcount) as Number_of_patients
FROM
(           
    SELECT users.users_id, users.name, patients.patients_id, count(*) as Rcount 
    FROM pecs 
    INNER JOIN users ON pecs.techniciens_id = users.users_id 
    INNER JOIN titles ON users.titles_id = titles.titles_id 
    INNER JOIN patients ON patients.patients_id = pecs.patients_id 
    GROUP BY users_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT users.users_id, users.name, patients.patients_id, count(*) as Rcount
    FROM followup 
    INNER JOIN users ON followup.technician_id = users.users_id 
    INNER JOIN titles ON users.titles_id = titles.titles_id 
    INNER JOIN pecs ON pecs.pecs_id = followup.pecs_id 
    INNER JOIN patients ON patients.patients_id = pecs.patients_id 
    GROUP BY users_id
)x 
GROUP BY users_id ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

the result is:

```
users_id    |   name    | Number_of_patients
40          |   ABABAB  | 223
```

that is 223 patients for technician_ID = 40

Now to view a list of the patients for this technician I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT patients.patients_id, patients.name
    FROM pecs 
    LEFT JOIN users ON pecs.techniciens_id = users.users_id  
    LEFT JOIN titles ON users.titles_id = titles.titles_id 
    INNER JOIN patients ON patients.patients_id = pecs.patients_id 
    WHERE pecs.techniciens_id = 40
    #GROUP BY patients_id
    UNION ALL       
    SELECT patients.patients_id, patients.name
    FROM followup 
    LEFT JOIN users ON followup.technician_id = users.users_id 
    LEFT JOIN titles ON users.titles_id = titles.titles_id 
    LEFT JOIN pecs ON pecs.pecs_id = followup.pecs_id 
    INNER JOIN patients ON patients.patients_id = pecs.patients_id 
    WHERE followup.technician_id = 40
    #GROUP BY patients_id
)x
GROUP BY patients_id ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

Now, I get the same number of records (223) but there are duplicates rows of patients ...I need help on how to get the correct number of patients for each technician without duplicates.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is illegible.  Please fix the formatting.  Also, you probably don't need this much information get an answer.  Pare down your question to a minimal sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood exactly your question.  Anyway, I would try to keep things as simple as possibile.  Regarding your "count" query, you could start from something like this, where I removed filed I think should not be useful for counting.  This query should give you count avoiding multiple id (I use DISTINCT in the two select and UNION to remove possible duplicate between the two select).  May be some join could be eliminated (but I don't know the whole structure).  Please follow Tim B. suggestion about formatting and care in posting a question.

```
SELECT USERS_ID, COUNT(*) AS PATIENTS_COUNT
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT USERS.USERS_ID, PATIENTS.PATIENTS_ID
        FROM PECS
        INNER JOIN USERS ON PECS.TECHNICIENS_ID = USERS.USERS_ID
        INNER JOIN TITLES ON USERS.TITLES_ID = TITLES.TITLES_ID
        INNER JOIN PATIENTS ON PATIENTS.PATIENTS_ID = PECS.PATIENTS_ID
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT USERS.USERS_ID, PATIENTS.PATIENTS_ID 
        FROM FOLLOWUP
        INNER JOIN USERS ON FOLLOWUP.TECHNICIAN_ID = USERS.USERS_ID
        INNER JOIN TITLES ON USERS.TITLES_ID = TITLES.TITLES_ID
        INNER JOIN PECS ON PECS.PECS_ID = FOLLOWUP.PECS_ID
        INNER JOIN PATIENTS ON PATIENTS.PATIENTS_ID = PECS.PATIENTS_ID
    ) A
```